# How to construct this query

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following 2 queries:

> SELECT CARD_ID,COUNT(CARD_ID) AS CNT1 FROM G_CARD_SCHEDULE GROUP BY
>   CARD_ID

Who's output is

```
CARD_ID     CNT1
119         1
120         2
```

> SELECT CARD_ID,COUNT(CARD_ID) AS CNT2 FROM G_SENT_TABLE GROUP BY
>   CARD_ID

Who's output is

```
CARD_ID     CNT2
115         2
120         1
```

Now my query should output using these 2

```
CARD_ID     CNT2
120         3
115         2
119         1
```

So basically i have to get a sum of them through the ID sorted. How do i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select card_id,count(card_id) as cnt2 from (
SELECT CARD_ID FROM G_CARD_SCHEDULE 
union all
SELECT CARD_ID FROM G_SENT_TABLE) as t
group by card_id
order by cnt2 desc
```

Comment: Ty so much! I didnt think about union at all! But you are using `as cnt2 as tot` 2 times as. Mysql didnt allow this. I removed the the `as tot` part

Comment: Sorry. Typo. I had edited my post with your alias after I had used tot as I ususally do ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT CARD_ID,
         COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM (SELECT card_id 
            FROM G_CARD_SCHEDULE
          UNION ALL
          SELECT card_id
            FROM G_SENT_TABLE) x
GROUP BY card_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT CARD_ID, COUNT(CARD_ID) FROM 
      (SELECT CARD_ID FROM G_CARD_SECHEDULE 
   UNION ALL 
       SELECT CARD_ID FROM G_SENT_TABLE)
   AS G_CARD_UNION GROUP BY CARD_ID;
```

... does that get what you wanted?